# Excel return address for future calculation

Tags: excel

I want to perform some calculation based on a time-series in Excel. The logic of the calculation is attached in the plot below:
[image]

I want to perform the calculation on a time series from the 1st date in time-series to the "Until" date. How do I let Excel automatically replace "C14" in the calculation cell with the correct address?

I used the function ADDRESS(MATCH(F2, A:A, 0), 3) to get "$C$14". However, I couldn't use this function to replace C14 in the calc() function, because it has extra "" quotes around it. How do I get rid of the quotes "" to fill in?

Comment: What do you want to calculate? The `SUM()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done using the `INDIRECT` function,

```
=INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(F2,A:A,0))
```

Assuming your until date is present in cell `F2`, the indirect formula will return the reference. You can add this to your calc formula.

Comment: @dxfkgdkjfgbizldu If you enter this as a seperate formula, then it will just return the value and not the reference. This has to be concatenated to your calc formula. Then only it will work. Now you have to tell me what is your calc formula so that i can help you out

Comment: @dxfkgdkjfgbizldu Thats great!!